# Issue Tracker from pre exsisting table

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am working on a project where I have lets say 5 customers. Each customer request inspections for their company through Gravity forms, Gravity Flow and Gravity View. Long story short, the inspectors find things and create types, notes and pictures. I will create  a "Issues DB table" for each company. So I will have 5 separate issue tables. I need something that I can use to connect a customer to their pre existent and evolving issue table and assign these issues to an email address based on what type of issue it is. I also will need permissions. Will also need filtering grouping, Im getting ideas together and was just wondering if there are any already built plugins. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, 3rd-party plugin recommendations are considered off-topic here